# How to search through tag results from :ts?

Tags: tags, ctags

If pressing `CTRL-]` matches multiple tags in Vim, it'll say "tag 1 of x or more". Typing `:ts` now shows you the list of x tags and allows you to choose which tag you want to jump to.

When I am in this list of tags screen, I have ~100 results and I'd like to search for a particular word that the result (tag) I want has. How can I do this?

Basically, I want to search through the `:ts` page as if it were text.